# How to format a number in SSRS Report for Matrix?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am formatting a number which is Date and I want to display only day and month part **(e.g. Jan 1, Jan 2, Jan 3, Jan 4…)** of this but it is not formatting and displaying the complete date.

**Whereas If I use the same wizard with tabular then it is working fine.**

I am using wizard to format data
[image]

**Is there any other way to format data while working with matrix ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try right clicking on the field in your SSRS report and using an expression for it instead.

[image]

Comment: sorry, it is not working with matrix. when using anything else in expression the it is repeating the same thing in all the columns.

e.g. I written =Day(Fields!DateWorking.Value) then it repeated same value in all columns of matrix.

Comment: You need to click the cell of the matrix, not the matrix itself.

Comment: it works.. earlier it was not working because I had also applied formatting from "Text Box property" window. when removed formatting of "Text Box property" and set it default and in expression I write =Day(Fields!DateWorked.Value) then it works.

Comment: but the Day function of SSRS considering date format as mm/dd/yyyy while sql was returning dd/mm/yyyy on same machine.. to resolve this I am returning only day part from SQL so I do not need to format it in SSRS. Anyway your answer is good and working

Answer (score 1):

In the altanative, you could use datename function in sql server for that Column

SELECT DATENAME(DAY,Col_Name)+', '+LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,Col_Name),3) 
that is 
SELECT DATENAME(DAY,'2016-03-21')+', '+LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH,'2016-03-21'),3)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to format dates outside that wizard is the format property. Click on the textbox and look in the Properties window for the Format property. Enter "MMM dd" into that field.

Alternatively, you can use a texbox formula as GabrielVA noted. I would recommend trying

```
=Format(Fields!Date.Value, "MMM dd")
```